# How Tensorflow does the differentiation for gradient descent optimizer?

Tags: optimization, tensorflow, training-data, gradient-descent

I did gradient descent optimizer with input X (24,1), output Y (6,1) and variables w,b, but the cost became to NaN in the first iteration even the learning rate was 1e-20. I checked the gradients values of w, and it became to all 0 in the first iteration. 

How Tensorflow does the differentiation for gradient descent optimizer? How could I figure out this problem?

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[1,n_func],name="X")
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[1,n_output], name="Y")

n_hl1 = n_output
# (24*6)
hidden_layer_1 = {'w': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_func, n_hl1]), name='h1w'),
                'b': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hl1]), name='h1b')}

# (1*24) (24*6) = (1*6)
l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(X,hidden_layer_1['w']), hidden_layer_1['b'])
l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

prediction = l1

# Cost
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(Y - prediction, name="cost"))

# rate
global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
starter_learning_rate = 1.0e-20
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(starter_learning_rate, global_step, epochs/10, 0.8, staircase=True)

# GradientDescentOptimizer
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost, global_step=global_step)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for _ in range(epochs):
        cost_value = 0
        learning_step = optimizer

        for i in range(n_test):
            c = 0
            _,c = sess.run([optimizer, cost],{X:h2[i],Y:[y[:,i]]})
            cost_value += c

        print cost_value
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing some code reproducing the described behaviour?

Comment: are there nan's in the gradient?

Comment: yes, NaN in gradient.